# MySQL Applying an "ORDER BY" clause to a UNION query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GET_DDLPage]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT NULL AS 'ID', '--None--' AS 'DSC'
    UNION
    SELECT MSP_NM AS 'ID', MSP_TITLE AS 'DSC'
    FROM MST_PAGE
    WHERE MSP_STS = ACTIVE ORDER BY MSP_NM
END
```

I get an error saying:

> MSP_NM is an invalid column

How do I fix this query and also order by `MSP_NM`?

Comment: This looks more like SQL Server syntax than it does MySQL, with the square braces around the identifier, and the reference to "dbo", the `ALTER PROCEDURE` statement ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is best to use a subquery for this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT NULL AS ID, '--None--' AS DSC
      UNION ALL
      SELECT MSP_NM AS ID, MSP_TITLE AS DSC
      FROM MST_PAGE
      WHERE MSP_STS = 'ACTIVE'
     ) t
ORDER BY ID;
```

You need quotes around `'ACTIVE'` and you can probably run the query without the subquery -- I just think the subquery clarifies the intention.

Comment: yesyes i recently change it to number to varchar hopin ppl to understand, thanks you sir , problem solve...